# Skipped Code causing program to end early

Tags: java, block, volume, calculator

I am currently trying to create a volume, Area, Surface Area, and perimeter calculator but I have run into little problem

```
package Volume;

public class C {
  static double r;
  static double h;

    static double volume() {
      return (25/7.957747154)*(r*r)*h;
    }

}
```

The data Class

```
package Volume;

import java.io.IOException;
import java.util.Scanner;

public class VC {
  public static void main(String args[]) 
    throws IOException {
      char s2;  
      char s1;
      Scanner first = new Scanner(System.in);
      Scanner second = new Scanner(System.in);
      a: {
      System.out.println("Chose your Type: \n1.Volume \n2.Area \n3.Surface Area \n4.Perimeter \n5.Exit \nPlease type the number of your option.");
      s1 = (char) System.in.read();
      switch(s1) {
        case '1':
        System.out.println("Chose Your Shape: \n1.Cylinder \ntype the number");
        s2 = (char) System.in.read();
        switch(s2) {
          case '1': 
          System.out.println("Raidius?");
          Volume.C.r = first.nextDouble();
          System.out.println("Height?");
          Volume.C.h = second.nextDouble();
          Double v;
          v = Volume.C.volume();
          System.out.println("The Volume is:" + v);
          break a;
       }
       case '5':
       System.out.println("GoodBye");
     }
   }
 }
}
```

The Main Class

The problem I run into is after I finish the first switch statement instead of pausing to read the char it skips that whole block and goes to case '5':
ending the program before anything is done.

Could someone please explain this to me?

Comment: Formatting your code properly might help your reason about it.

Comment: it was formatted till I put it here

Comment: Was your intent to have a while loop in there somewhere??

Comment: @Joey, paste your code again. Then highlight it. Then press Ctrl+k

Comment: Are you sure you want to nest switch / case statements like that? Why not jump to specific methods for volume, area, surface area, etc. It would greatly improve readability.

Comment: I do jump like that the method for the cylinders volume is in its own class along with its variables. The nesting is so I can Allow whoever interacts with the program to navigate to what Kind of operation the need with whatever shape. the program is far from complete.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

IO buffering is a source to many problems, I would suggest that you:

1. Access `System.in` only through a Scanner (e.g. no `System.in.read`)
2. Create only a single Scanner for he same stream (e.g., only `first`, no `second`)

Some more explanation:

You are accessing the standard input stream (e.g. the user input) through 3 different objects:

- `first` - `System.in` wrapped by `Scanner`
- `second` - `System.in` wrapped by `Scanner`
- Directly in some places, for example `s2 = (char) System.in.read();`

Instead, create only one `Scanner` and use it for all the reads from `System.in`

Comment: I Figured it out Thank you very much for your help sir now onto every other part of the program

Comment: Ok new question Now I'm having a similar problem with break statement?